# VBA - Copy 6 Rows with Formulas and Insert after each change in value

Tags: vba, excel

New to forum and no VBA experience.

I am not all that familiar with the terminology, so forgive me if I use some incorrect language here...I started searching for VBA codes yesterday with some luck but nothing exactly what I need so I'm hoping someone out there can educate me. I would like to run a macro that automatically copies 6 consecutive rows with formulas and conditional formatting from my template sheet, then inserts them with all the formulas and formatting intact after each change in value, specifically after each date change. As of right now, I can use the following code then filter to blanks and manually paste the cells but it's not much better than just copying and inserting rows with no code. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated and I can post the sheet if needed.  Thanks in advance!

```
Sub InsertRowAtChangeInValue()

    Dim lRow As Long

    For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(lRow, "B") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "B") Then
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

Comment: How exactly is the value ("date") changing?  FYI - A great way to start familiarizing yourself with VBA is to record macros and see what code is generated for you.  It wont be pretty and wont use best practices but gives you a jump on learning how VBA works.  Even better is to open the module next to your sheet while your recording so you can watch the code appear as you make changes to your sheet.

Comment: I will try that, thanks...basically, I have hundreds of lines that show a schedule which is sorted by date and sometimes 20 jobs (20 consecutive rows) of data will have the same date so after each date, I have totals for each type of job and other formulas that give me the daily numbers I need.

Comment: post your worksheet and if possible clearly state your requirement to the point.

Comment: I can post the sheet tomorrow but this is what I have so far. If there is a way to hold the conditional formatting when inserted using this code, that would be great.

Sub InsertRowAtChangeInValue()

    Dim lRow As Long

    For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(lRow, "B") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "B") Then
            Sheets("Template").Select
            Rows("2:7").Select
            Selection.Copy
               Sheets("Current").Select
               Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to delete this but I was able to get everything to work using the following:

Sub InsertRowAtChangeInValue()

```
    Sheets("dfw production schedule").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Current").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A2").Select

Dim lRow As Long

For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(lRow, "B") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "B") Then
        Sheets("Template").Select
        Rows("2:7").Select
        Selection.Copy
           Sheets("Current").Select
           Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next lRow
```

End Sub